# Unable to get repr for <class 'activities.models.Image'>

Tags: django, debugging

When I try to load an admin edit page with image inliner, I get a weird object which crashes my page. This thing goes last after all my images are loaded.

What can it be?

[image]

### Code

**models.py**

```
class Image(BaseImage):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, verbose_name=u'Новость', null=True)
    in_preview = models.BooleanField(u'Отображать в превью', default=False)
    weight = models.IntegerField(u'Порядок', default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Изображение'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Изображения'
        ordering = ('weight',)

    def get_upload_to(self, filename):
        return os.path.join('articles', 'image', 'image_file', filename)

    def list_thumbnail_tag(self):
        source = self.image_file
        if source:
            thumbnail = get_thumbnailer(source).get_thumbnail({'size': (100, 100), 'crop': True})
            return '<img src="{}">'.format(thumbnail.url)

    list_thumbnail_tag.short_description = 'Превью'
    list_thumbnail_tag.allow_tags = True

class BaseImage(models.Model):
    image_file = models.ImageField(u'Файл', upload_to='uploads')
    image_alt = models.CharField(u'Атрибут Alt', max_length=255, blank=True)
    image_title = models.CharField(u'Название', max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.image_file.path)

    def get_upload_to(self, filename):
        return os.path.join('images', filename)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        verbose_name = u'Изображение'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Изображения'
```

Comment: I would recommend you to show us some code and the trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like the error message says: the `__str__` method on BaseImage calls `image_file.path`, but the particular instance you're looking at has no image_file set.

You should use a value that doesn't depend on that field being set, or deal with that case somehow.